# Como bloquear tradução em um elemento/tag HTML

Tags: html

```
<div id="title-div">
    <h3 id="title">C<i class="fas fa-virus"></i>vid-19 in&nbsp</h3><h3 id="in-country">loading...</h3>
</div>
```

Preciso que a tag h3 com id "title" não seja traduzida, pois o ícone do fontawesome muda de posição quando a página é traduzida e não dá o efeito desejado (pelo menos foi oque aconteceu quando testei)

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso no próprio HTML ou se necessário, no JS? (**BLOQUEAR TRADUÇÕES EM DETERMINADO ELEMENTO**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pode adicionar, para a tag que contém o texto a não ser traduzido, o [atributo `translate`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_translate.asp) na tag ou se a ferramenta de tradução for Google Translate, usar uma `class` com valor [`notranslate`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_translate.asp).

Por via das dúvidas, teste com os dois:

```
<div id="title-div">
    <h3 id="title" class="notranslate" translate="no">C<i class="fas fa-virus"></i>vid-19 in&nbsp</h3><h3 id="in-country">loading...</h3>
</div>
```

<sub>**obs**: não tenho certeza se funciona em todos os navegadores...</sub>